# Confused about Term Store for use in cross site publishing

Tags: content-query-web-part, term-store, cross-site-publishing

I'm trying to use a content query webpart to show information on a list from another site collection. I've enabled the cross site publishing feature on the site that contains the list. I've enabled the list as a catalog. On the "Navigation Hierarchy" field, my only option is "none". I've performed a crawl on the list.

What needs to be added to the term store in order to query the list from another site? When I go to the term store settings for the site containing the list I've selected the site collection term group and allowed access to the site I want to query from. There are no terms sets in the group though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong web part. 'Content Search' web part is the one I needed. This is now less confusing.

Comment: It took me a long time to find the content search web part -- none of the documentation or tutorials says where it is. It can be found in the "Content Rollup group" NOT the "Search group"